# RegularExpression C#, matching group

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text looking like this:

````
My arbitrary content....

```c#
public class Foo
{
    //Some code
}
```
My other arbitrary content....
````

I want to find all blocks starting with:

````
```c#
````

and ending with:

````
```
````

and replace it with the content between these start and end tags, so that the result becomes:

```
My arbitrary content....

public class Foo
{
    //Some code
}

My other arbitrary content....
```

How would that look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to remove the triple backtick style markers and leave the rest of the document unchanged.

````
text = Regex.Replace(
      text,
      @"^```c#\r?\n(.*?)```\r?\n", "$1",
      RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
````

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/wwZBq)

Comment: Doesn't there need to be start ^ and end $ since it could be multiple blocks?